# How can I have 2 rewrite rules on my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have an .htaccess file that has one rewrite rule that removes .html however I cannot seem to be able to do the same thing with .php without messing up my whole website
This is the code that I have in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, why not?

Your version:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Some lightly modified version:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [END]
```

You generally should switch off `MultiViews` when implementing such rules by the way.